Safe conversion from character to numeric in R
I have a dataframe in R (height is currently character):
sampledf = structure(list(person_name = c("Charlie", "Charlie", "Julia", 
"Bob", "Fatima", "Erik", "Diana", "Fatima", "Ian", "Julia", "Erik", 
"Charlie", "Ian", "Ian", "Ian", "Charlie", "Hannah", "Julia", 
"George", "Julia"), country = c("USA", "Sweden", "India", "USA", 
"Sweden", "Brazil", "India", "Japan", "Brazil", "USA", "USA", 
"Japan", "Sweden", "India", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Sweden", "USA", 
"Japan", "Brazil"), height = c("175 cm", "162cm", "168", "not measured", 
"155 cm", "height not provided", "180", "declined", "172 cm",     "165", "N/A", "178 cm", "150cm", "refuse to share", "169", "177 cm", 
"182", "173 cm", "unknown", "158 cm")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = "data.frame")


  person_name country              height
1      Charlie     USA              175 cm
2      Charlie  Sweden               162cm
3        Julia   India                 168
4          Bob     USA        not measured
5       Fatima  Sweden              155 cm
6         Erik  Brazil height not provided
7        Diana   India                 180
8       Fatima   Japan            declined
9          Ian  Brazil              172 cm
10       Julia     USA                 165
11        Erik     USA                 N/A
12     Charlie   Japan              178 cm
13         Ian  Sweden               150cm
14         Ian   India     refuse to share
15         Ian  Brazil                 169
16     Charlie  Brazil              177 cm
17      Hannah  Sweden                 182
18       Julia     USA              173 cm
19      George   Japan             unknown
20       Julia  Brazil              158 cm

I want to find out the average height per country.
I am wondering: is this a safe way for converting from character to numeric and then proceed with the average?
sampledf$height  = as.numeric(as.character(sampledf$height))
aggregate(height ~ country, data=sampledf, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)

Ideally anything that can not be converted to numeric is simply made as NA and then ignored in the averaging. Is this correct?

You can use parse_number from readr package
library(readr)
sampledf$height <- parse_number(sampledf$height)
aggregate(height ~ country, data = sampledf, FUN = mean)
  country height
1  Brazil 169.00
2   India 174.00
3   Japan 178.00
4  Sweden 162.25
5     USA 171.00


Try
transform(sampledf, height2 = strtoi(sub("\\D+", "", height))) |>
  aggregate(height2 ~ country, data = _, FUN = mean)

  country height2
1  Brazil  169.00
2   India  174.00
3   Japan  178.00
4  Sweden  162.25
5     USA  171.00

We introduce height2 here. Perhaps, height carries information we want to use in an intermediate step.

It's really only "safe" if you know you have some consistent rules that will hold true for parsing the numeric values. Are they all cm? Does the number always come first? Any whitespace?
For instance, regex to take any leading digits as height in cm. The as.numeric() will return NA when a number wasn't parsed by sub().
sampledf$height_parsed <- with(
  sampledf,
  as.numeric(sub("^(\\d+).*?$", "\\1", height))
)
#> Warning in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()): NAs
#> introduced by coercion

aggregate(height_parsed ~ country, data = sampledf, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#>   country height_parsed
#> 1  Brazil        169.00
#> 2   India        174.00
#> 3   Japan        178.00
#> 4  Sweden        162.25
#> 5     USA        171.00

Also note the formula method for aggregate() below. Any other arguments in ... not specified here are passed to your function. So na.rm is passed to mean()
## S3 method for class 'formula'
aggregate(x, data, FUN, ...,
          subset, na.action = na.omit)


tapply and gsub could be another solution:
library(tibble);library(dplyr)

with(sampledf, 
     tapply(height, country, FUN = \(z) {
         z<-gsub("[^0-9.-]",'',z) |> as.numeric()
         mean(z, na.rm=T)
     }, simplify = T
     ) |> as.data.frame() |> rownames_to_column(var = "country") |> rename(height=c(2))
)

output
  country height
1  Brazil 169.00
2   India 174.00
3   Japan 178.00
4  Sweden 162.25
5     USA 171.00


You are missing at least one library-call
